# Seed Inertia form from Pinia Store on component load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs, pinia

I've a component, a modal in the specific case, that should load the data, previously load to a pinia store, directly to the Inertia form.

The component script...

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { userStore } from "@Stores/User";

const userInfo = userStore();

const user = computed(() => userInfo.getUserDetails);
    
const form = useForm({
    name: user.value.name,
    email: user.value.email,
    avatar: user.value.avatar,
});

function loadData() {
    // form.name = user.value.name;
    // form.email = user.value.email;
    // form.avatar = user.value.avatar;
}
</script>
```

Using the `onMounted` function i'm able to understand that, when mounted, the variable user is empty and 200ms later is correctly seeded.
It wasn't supposed the data of the form to be updated once the user variable gets the data from the store?

I'm able to seed the form from the function loadData, but that way i loose the functionalities that the Inertia form allows, just as `isDirty`.

Is there a way of seeding the form from the store in a reactive way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form.defaults()` to seed the form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.